# Android SQLite best practice for memory performance

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-memory

Considering a SQLite database of ~200k rows and a read access every 10 seconds, what is the best practice for memory performance?

- [`Open`, `Request`, `Close` ] every 10 seconds

or

- `Open`, [`Request`] Every 10 seconds, `Close`

Comment: First you should ask yourself why have 200k records in an Android app. About the question, in Android it's recommended to open the DB once at the start of your app and close when it's finished (loses focus).

Comment: Thank you for your response. 200k records are normal, there is no leak with it. I'm just wondering if closing database allow to free memory resources to execute other tasks, as handling results.

Comment: "Best practice" means that you have identified all possible practices, measured them and selected the "best" by comparing those measures with your "best" criteria.  This describes what you should do to determine best practice. Without this, how can someone else determine it?  As m0skit0 says, the recommended practice is to open once since opening is an expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you, I identified this two possibles practices, but how can I measure memory allocation during "Open file" process? Is the memory populated by the database content?

Comment: It's tough. MAT is your best bet but memory usage is not as simple as "what was it before compared to what is it now". The database is not loaded into memory. Rather, result sets of selected rows are loaded into cursors, which themselves implement caching. Another way of saying that is "take a database with 10 rows". Open it. Some memory is used. Without changing anything, add 1000 rows and open.  Isolate every other change outside the act of opening the database (good luck!), that memory used would be the same of very similar to the first case. Only when you query does it change.

Comment: Thank you very much for these comments, consider it as "accepted answer"